# Finding Pitch Diameter of sprocket

Tags: algebra-precalculus, divisibility

I am currently following a tutorial on Instructables [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-draw-a-sproket-in-autodesk-inventor-7/step3/calculate-2/). In the instructable to find the pitch diameter of a sprocket they use the formula on the above link. the pitch that is used is 12.70, the roller diameter is 7.92 but is rounded up to 8. I am having trouble getting the same result as shown 61.083. Maybe I am doing it wrong I first take the number of teeth "15" divide it by 180 and get 12. I then divide that by 12.70 to get 1.0583. In the formula used there is "sen" next to the parentheses I am unsure of what that is. Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong here step by step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "sen" in the formula is a sine; this is common notation in Spanish texts.  Therefore what you need to compute is

$$\frac{12.7}{\sin{12^{\circ}}} \approx \frac{12.7}{0.207912} \approx 61.0836$$

Comment: That was it thank you so much I just posted to stack overflow because I found a working JavaScript example and was running into the same issue. I don't understand what "sine" is so I will have to research it